# My INSERT query always add two row

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a table (which has two columns `id`, which is an auto increment column, and `name`), and when I try to add a new row by using insert query an empty row added with basic row .
any one know why this happens?

Here is my PHP code:

```
$category_name = $_POST['category_name'];           
$result = mysql_query(
    "INSERT into agent_categories (agent_cat_type) values('$category_name')"
);
```

Comment: Add more code - whats happenning around these lines?

Comment: Your code is ok. The problem is not there. Show your db structure and more code.
P.S: Do not use mysql_* functions, they are deprecated.

Comment: write actual code that you are using

Comment: Use echo $_POST['category_name']; to be sure it has some content.

Comment: What's the value of `$category_name`? You aren't escaping anything, so maybe `$category_name == "name1'),('"`?

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) will help you avoid making mistakes like this.

Comment: problem is in codes which you did not provide

Comment: How do you know you're getting an extra row? (Please describe the technique you're using to view the results in your data base.) What is in that row?

Comment: Try disabling your browser extensions if you have any. I know of some FirePHP extensions that duplicate each HTTP request you make, resulting in things like this.

Comment: This often happens if you: 1) have faulty rewrite rules in your web server which are causing the page to be called twice (check your server access logs and you'll see each request line duplicated) or 2) you have an image or script with an empty `src=` attribute, causing the _current URI_ to be called by the browser as that `<img>` or `<script>` source.. Check your HTML markup.